# Matlab Question on Sparse Matrices

Tags: matlab, normalization, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix S.
I perform the following operation
`D1 = diag(sum(S,2))`, basically forming a diagonal matrix.
Now I need to perform `(D1)^(-0.5)`, but I get an error
"Error using mpower, use full(x)^full(y)"

Converting to full will defeat the purpose of using a sparse matrix.

Any advice will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Raising a diagonal matrix to a power can be done simply by doing the operation on the diagonal elements elementwise... so:

```
D1_diagonal_elements = sum(S,2);
your_result = diag(D1_diagonal_elements .^ (-0.5));
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but get "error using power, Out of memory"

Comment: It works for positive powers, for negative powers I get that error.

Comment: Well... that is quite a big matrix then, not even the full diagonal fits into memory :) The cause is likely that since x.^(-0.5)==1/sqrt(x), all the zero elements of the sparse diagonal get converted to Inf's, practically converting the vector to a full one. Btw: what do you want to use the result for? Could you first collect the nonzero elements and then get rid of the remaining Inf's?

Comment: Well I'm trying to perform co-clustering on a large matrix. For that, using the Dhillon's algorithm where I first need to convert the sparse input matrix to X = D1_root*A*D2_root, where D1_root = abs((D1)^(-0.5)) and like wise for D2_root. D1 = diag(sum(A,2)), D2 = diag(sum(A,1)). A is the input sparse matrix. I see what you are saying, let me try something else. Thanks much!